# Scraping from Coindix

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm pretty new to Python, so would like some guidance. I would like to pull "Name, Protocol, APY, TVL" data from https://coindix.com/?sort=-tvl by scraping (as I believe there is no API), but having some issue. When I execute below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coindix.com/?sort=-tvl"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
```

the returned data does not include the information I would like to get. Could someone please help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's an api. Find the url in Dev Tools -> Network -> XHR -> Headers

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://apiv2.coindix.com/search'
payload = {
    'sort': '-tvl',
    'first': 'true',
    'screen': '1114'}  

data = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()['data']  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(5).to_string())
      id           name                                               icon     chain protocol      base  reward          rewards       apy  apy_7_day         tvl  risk                                            link  is_new
0  17419            UST            https://apiv2.coindix.com/icons/UST.png     Terra   Anchor  0.193600  0.0000               {}  0.193600    0.19570  5977961341     2  https://apiv2.coindix.com/vault/17419/redirect   False
1  17206  DAI-USDC-USDT  https://apiv2.coindix.com/icons/DAI-USDC-USDT.png  Ethereum    Curve  0.002800  0.0087  {'CRV': 0.0087}  0.011500    0.01210  5952854016     1  https://apiv2.coindix.com/vault/17206/redirect   False
2  17174           LUNA           https://apiv2.coindix.com/icons/LUNA.png     Terra     Lido  0.079000  0.0000               {}  0.079000    0.07900  5534798290     1  https://apiv2.coindix.com/vault/17174/redirect   False
3  15940            ETH            https://apiv2.coindix.com/icons/ETH.png  Ethereum     Lido  0.047000  0.0000               {}  0.047000    0.04700  5347746431     1  https://apiv2.coindix.com/vault/15940/redirect   False
4  13517      cUSD-cEUR      https://apiv2.coindix.com/icons/cUSD-cEUR.png      Celo    Sushi  0.002466  0.0000               {}  0.002466    0.01058  4609514119     2  https://apiv2.coindix.com/vault/13517/redirect   False

[100 rows x 14 columns]
```